# What happens if i close the Dynamic Link Library using "free" instead of "dlclose"?

Tags: c, linux, dll

Today,i check my code, i found close the DLL use the "free" instead of "dlclose", like this:

```
//...
static void * s_lib_general_board_io = dlopen(sLibName, RTLD_NOW);
//...
free(s_lib_general_board_io); //shoud be use "dlclose"
```

That doesn't look like anything happened, which made me wonder.

Will that cause a memory leak?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, probably. Sometimes it crashes, sometimes it leaks memory.

Comment: If it is not crashing or otherwise reporting problems in the `free`, it may be that `dlopen` returns a pointer to memory allocated for the loaded library, and passing it to `free` releases that memory but does not close or unmap the library file or release other resources related to the `dlopen`. If you are lucky, it would just waste resources as long as the library is not used anymore. But it is nothing you should rely on; the code should be fixed.